# Set the scope of an eval

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to set the global of an eval? I would like to set the global of an eval so I don't have to prefix everything with `obj`.

If I do the following, I get an error

> ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined

```
let obj = {
  MyClass: class MyClass {
    static CallMe() {}
  }
}

eval(`
  'use strict';
  global = obj;
  result = MyClass.CallMe();
`)
```

However, If I do this:

```
result = obj.MyClass.CallMe();
```

It works, but I would like to make it so I don't have to prefix the call with obj. Is there any why that this can be done?

Comment: Why are you using `eval(` here?  Why not simple JavaScript?

Comment: As far as I know, the only possible way to do this is with [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) but don't do it

Comment: I am creating a templating tool, and the data that comes from the template are formatted as strings

Comment: Nooo! Parse the strings properly then! this is a *How to build a footgun?* question

Comment: How would you parse the strings properly than?

Comment: So... you're allowing users to provide arbitrary data, which you're then parsing as code for evaluation to interpolate into the template? Absolutely not. This is a great way to leave your code open to being exploited. For instance, if in one of these interpolated strings I passed `"document.write('new content')"` your engine would overwrite the page contents entirely. And that's a very, VERY simple and benign example. Do not do this. Use JS's template strings, or create a full parser; don't execute arbitrary code with eval.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the [`vm` module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)?

Comment: "How would you parse the strings properly than?" That depends on what you're going to allow the user to run, and why you're doing this at all instead of using one of the many existing templating engines that have been time-tested and had security holes fixed already.

Comment: @Bergi that seems to work exactly in the way that I was looking for!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn From the top of the documentation on the vm module page: "The vm module is not a security mechanism. Do not use it to run untrusted code." Even with that module, please please please do not use it to run arbitrary code.

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why you need to use `eval` here, but if you do, you can use `with (obj)` in your evaluated code:

```
eval(`
    'use strict';
     with (obj) {
         result = MyClass.CallMe();
     }
`);
```

I still feel like you shouldn't be using eval here (what use is it?), as it's easy to accidentally open yourself to injection vulnerabilities if you're not careful. What are you using eval for here? Maybe we can point out a better way.

Comment: You can't use `with` with strict mode

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Then I don't know of a way to make this work (though, once again, I'm also not convinced it SHOULD be done this way anyway).

Comment: Backing argument for the *don't do this*: `eval` and `with` both make it impossible for the engine to do *any* optimizations, thus it will fall back to a very basic (and very very slow) way of interpreting the code. Not to mention the many fun errors you'll get with this that you can't trace back

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea why you'd like to use eval, especially in such weird way but this might be something that you are looking for:

```
class MyClass {
    static CallMe() {
        return 'sample';
    }
}

eval(`
  'use strict';
  let result = MyClass.CallMe();
  console.log(result);
`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have warned you already about the risks of using `eval`so I won't be doing that myself.

I certainly found some legitimate use cases for `eval` in a *controlled* environment. I am assuming that you know what you're doing.

This *may or may not* be useful:

```js
let obj1 = {
  foo: () => console.log('scope: obj1')
};

let obj2 = {
  foo: () => console.log('scope: obj2')
};


const scopedEval = (context, code) =>
  new Function('global', code)(context, code);

scopedEval(obj1, `
  global.foo();
`)

scopedEval(obj2, `
  global.foo();
`)
```